# Why does DrRacket IDE considers some identifiers as "symbols" and some as "keywords"? What is the difference?

Tags: scheme, binding, keywords, racket

Why does DrRacket (kind of Scheme) IDE highlights some of the identifiers as "keywords" (for example `define`, `lambda`, `send*`), and the others as "symbols" (user defined identifiers, `+`, `-`, `abs`, `send`, `send+`, etc.)?

I am particularly confused by the difference between `send*` and `send+`.  For reference, here are the beginnings of their definitions:

```
(define-syntax (send* stx) ...

(define-syntax (send+ stx) ...
```

(It is possible that I do not use the terms "identifier", "symbol", and "keyword" completely correctly, but this is how some of them seem to be used in DrRacket preferences.)

Unless this is a bug, it must be explained by the language "semantics", so I decided to ask here.

Answer (score 2):

DrRacket maintains a list of keywords that it understands for auto-indentation, which you can find in the Preferences (under Editing->Indenting). If an identifier is listed as a keyword for indentation, then DrRacket will also highlight it differently if the chosen color scheme differentiates keywords from plain identifiers.

Identifiers like `+` are not highlighted because they are just names of functions, not "special forms" like `if` and `cond`. On the other hand, `send+` isn't highlighted just because the default DrRacket keywords don't contain every syntactic form provided by Racket.

Comment: Is this a bug then?

Comment: I mean, who decides which identifiers are keywords? How should i maintain the lists of keywords?

Comment: You can add keywords yourself in the preferences. If you think it should go in the default list, you can submit a bug report or ask on the Racket mailing list.